# DispatcherServlet not forwarding my request to the controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

I am using spring framework for writing a web service application. There are not html or jsp pages in the application. It is purely web service. 
 **This is my Controller class**

```
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class Opinion {


    private FeedbackService fs;

    public Opinion(FeedbackService fs){


        this.fs=fs;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/givefeedback",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void Login(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        serialize.Feedback feedback=(serialize.Feedback)in.readObject();
        fs.writeFeedback(feedback);
        response.setStatus(200);


    }
```

**My mvc-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="poll_Web" class="sef.controller.Opinion">
        <constructor-arg ref="feedbackService" />
        </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="sef.controller" />



</beans>
```

**My web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>opinionDispacher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value> classpath:repository-config.xml /WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml 
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>opinionDispacher</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value> classpath:repository-config.xml /WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml 
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

I am using the URL `localhost:8080/feedback/givefeedback`. The app is deployed as **feedback.war**. But the request is not at all forwarded to the controller. I am not sure why is this is happening. I am also not sure till which point the request goes in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

from your servlet context configuration. This element will discover `@Controller` beans and their `@RequestMapping` methods and register them as handlers.

You'll need to add the appropriate XML namespace and schema location for that namespace.

---

Make `Opinion` a `@Controller` and remove

```
@RequestMapping("/*")
```

it doesn't really serve any purpose.

Comment: If I make Opinios a controller, I get exception during deployment saying that "bean opinion could not be created"

Comment: @ashwin Add a `@Autowired` annotation to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have also defined the `Opinion` bean twice in `mvc-config.xml`.  Remove bean definition for bean id `poll_Web`.

Comment: Bean Opinion is defined only once in mvc-config.xml. Where is the second one?

Comment: `<context:component-scan base-package="sef.controller" />` - this will scan the package and create bean defined using annotation.  E.g. `@Controller`

Comment: You can find more about component-scan [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html)